# Sonarqube-Jenkins-maven Intergate

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Please check my new pipeline is : now it is intergrating with maven.
**NEW PIPELINE-**

```
 stage('Test & code quality check ') {
      withMaven(maven: 'M3'){
    withSonarQubeEnv(credentialsId:'mbk-sonar',installationName:'sonar-qube') {
        sh '''mvn sonar:sonar -X  -f  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/pom.xml \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=mobikwik-jenkins \
  -Dsonar.projectName=mobikwik-jenkins \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.20.15.26:9000 \
  -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
  -Dsonar.language=java \
  -Dsonar.sources=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cabs-stag/cabs-stagSrc/shared-objects/src/main/ '''
    }
      }
  }
```

ERROR:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqcx5.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because jenkins is not able to recognise maven.

> Pre-requisite: You must have configured Sonarqube with Jenkins.

Follow the following steps to rectify your issue:

1. Download the Maven plugin in Jenkins or if you have already downloaded skip to next step.
2. In the `Manage Jenkins >> Global Tool Configuration >> Maven`, setup the MAVEN HOME path if you have download the maven binaries or select install automatically. Give any name.
   [image]
3. Go to Jenkins pipeline script and the maven tool. Use like this:

   ```
   pipeline {
      agent any

      tools { 
        maven 'Maven' 
          }

     stages {
     stage ('Initialize') {
       steps {
           sh '''
               echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
               echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
           ''' 
       }
   }

   stage ('Build') {
       steps {
           echo 'This is a minimal pipeline.'
            sh 'mvn clean install'
       }
   }
     stage('SonarCloud') {

    withSonarQubeEnv(credentialsId:'mbksonar',installationName:'sonar-qube') 
   {

   sh '''mvn sonar:sonar \
     -Dsonar.projectKey=XU6rO8Zce5RaXOtIiWF0dEbmscjiM8qX \
     -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.mobikwik.com \
     -Dsonar.sources=src/main \
     -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
     -Dsonar.language=java \
     -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes \
     -Dsonar.login=jenkins'''
    }

   }

     }
    }
   ```

Comment: please check my question again, i have updated it with answer and same error is coming

Comment: Do you have `sonar-maven-plugin` in your pom.xml or not ???

Comment: i am trying to integrate it with no addition to maven , i read somewhere that there is no need to add configuration to maven, i have updated jenkins piepleine please check my question part again, no face another error